# Receiving custom attributes from an external identity provider using OAUTH for SSO?

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, saml, identity

My situation here is that I want my Salesforce Digital Experience (AKA Community) to use an external identity provider that holds some custom access rights attributes that need to be transferred to Salesforce to influence what the Digital Experience presents. This is the [Salesforce as a Service Provider](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sso_sfdc_sp_rp_parent.htm&type=5) case.

For SAML, it looks like hooking in an implementation of the [SamlJitHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_Auth_SamlJitHandler.htm) that is passed all of the attributes of the SAML assertion will solve this problem.

But I don't see an equivalent ready to go mechanism for OAUTH. Is there one?

**PS**

Writing this question I just found this question [Any way to get current session SSO information?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205035/any-way-to-get-current-session-sso-information) that has an answer that points to the [AuthProviderPluginClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm). If you have experience with that do post an answer.

Comment: The answer you linked to still reflects the current state of the art. For OAuth and OpenID Connect (a superset of OAuth), another option is to make a callout to your external identity provider and hit the protocol-standard introspection and/or userinfo endpoint in the Login Flow. That might save you from writing a custom auth provider and/or dealing with protocol issues.

Comment: Thanks @identigral for the info.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on your requirements. If your Identity provider can work with OpenIdConnect I would configure this as a Salesforce Auth. provider and then use a custom registration handler using the RegistrationHandler interface. This uses the login procedure to identify / create or update users on login.
Salesforce documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_auth_plugin.htm#apex_auth_plugin)

Then you can use the attributemap within the userdata variable can be used to retrieve any custom attributes that are being send with the request. This can then be used in any way you would like.

```
global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){ 
 String myCustomAttribute = data.attributeMap.get('custom_attribute')
}
```